# How to read sql instruction for file

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

How to return values of external file?

I try but not work. No return values on the fetchall().

```
#customers.sql
SELECT * FROM customers;

#main.py
#!python3
#...
def insert_for_file(self):
    with open('customers.sql', 'rt') as f:
        d = f.read()
        r = self.db.cursor.executescript(d)
        print(r.fetchall())
```

Comment: To be sure the problem lies where you think, if you just change d = f.read() by d = 'SELECT * FROM customers', does it do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: I use execute(d) only.

Comment: please put whole code in answer, `execute(d)` does not clarify where to put. And put some explanation to your solution which may help others too.